# How to select the clickable parent in my React component even if I click on its children or anywhere else inside the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started an application which I want to work same as [weather.com](https://weather.com/en-AU/weather/today/l/ASXX0023:1:AS)  next 36 hours section. The idea is when you click on each weatherCard which has a seperate component in my app you will update the below section which is my weatherDetails component based on the selected weatherCard /weather box. So I made the entire component clickable by giving it the click event via props from my stateful component which is my weatherLocation component. This is my WeatherCard component:

```
const WeatherCard = (props) => (
<div id={props.date} className="weatherCard" onClick={props.clicked}>
    <h2 className="cardDate">{props.date}</h2>
    <h4>{props.forcast}</h4>
    <div className="minmaxDeg">
        <data>{props.min}</data>
        <data>{props.max}</data>
    </div>
    <data>{props.rain}</data>
</div>
);
```

And here in render method in WeatherLocation component I loop through data coming from state and give props the WeatherCard component:

```
const WeatherCards = this.state.reports.map( report => {
        return(
            <WeatherCard
            key={report.id}
            {...report}
            clicked={() => this.handleCardClick(event)}
            />
        );
    });
```

And this is the handleCardClick that I added for it just for testing:

```
handleCardClick = event => {
    // const { reports , selectedCardInfo , activeCard } = this.state;
    const selectedDate = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

I don't want to use anchor tag as I don't need href. The click works fine by itself. But because I need to get the id of the parent which is the div with the class of weatherCard. At the moment when I click on other elements inside the card I cannot get the id because they are not the parent. The reason I need its id is when I get data with from the API I need a unique value for each card so that when you click on the card the data for that card will be shown in the other component which is the WeatherDetails component. But for now I need to be able  to somehow choose that selected card and pull out the state for that unique card. Could someone  help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the Parent component ID to your onClick function in Weather Card.

Here is your WeatherCard - Component

```
const WeatherCard = (props) => (
<div id={props.date} className="weatherCard" onClick={event => props.clicked(event, props.id)}>
    <h2 className="cardDate">{props.date}</h2>
    <h4>{props.forcast}</h4>
    <div className="minmaxDeg">
        <data>{props.min}</data>
        <data>{props.max}</data>
    </div>
    <data>{props.rain}</data>
</div>
);
```

You can see that I have added `props.id` to your onClick function and with help of event now you can access that id from the parent component.

Now here is your Parent Component- WeatherCards

```
const WeatherCards = this.state.reports.map( (report, i) => {
        return(
            <WeatherCard
            key={report.id}
            id={i}
            {...report}
            clicked={this.handleCardClick}
            />
        );
    });
```

You can see in the code I am passing index number as id to your child component.
So this will give you an id (for now it's an index number) of the card in your onClick handler.

and Finally, here is your on click handler.

```
handleCardClick = (event, weatherCardID) => {
      console.log(weatherCardID)
}
```

As of now, I am using the index as id if you want to use a unique identifier, you can change that easily.

Answer (score 0):

General JavaScript solution is to differentiate the elements and `.stopPropogation` after you've captured the event you are targeting. A nested unordered list, `<ul>`would be an example. Tag the containing `<li>` with an `.opened` class upon rendering/displaying each level of nesting, tag those `<li>` elements accordingly, e.g. a dataset attribute such as `data-make`, then `data-model`, then `data-option`. You then attach and fire event listeners on the different level `<li>`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @RutulPatel. I made your answer as the answer. But I changed your code a bit as I got your point so I wrote an answer as it is long. I think we might not need to change the WeatherCard at all and I don't pass event or any logic there. so it will be intact:

```
    const WeatherCard = (props) => (
<div id={props.date} className="weatherCard" onClick={event => props.clicked(event, props.id)}>
    <h2 className="cardDate">{props.date}</h2>
    <h4>{props.forcast}</h4>
    <div className="minmaxDeg">
        <data>{props.min}</data>
        <data>{props.max}</data>
    </div>
    <data>{props.rain}</data>
</div>
);
```

But I use your tip changing my weatherCards array to look like this:

```
const weatherCards = this.state.reports.map( report => {
        return(
            <WeatherCard
            key={report.id}
            id={report.date}
            {...report}
            clicked={() => this.handleCardClick(event, report.date)}
            />
        );
    });
```

So I use the report.date which is a unique value as my id. Also I don't pass event as a parameter to the arrow function I just pass it with the report.date to the handler:

```
clicked={() => this.handleCardClick(event, report.date)}
```

And the handler will be the same as you did:

```
handleCardClick = (event, weatherCardID) => {
  console.log(weatherCardID)
}
```

I might even remove event later on from both if there was no need fo that.

Thank you again.

Comment: Well, Thanks for your reply. I have a reason to pass the event, just because if you want to use any params from the event you can use it. for example ( you can keep track of your history, avoid multiple clicks and more)

Comment: Thanks @RutulPatel. You are right and that is excellent. I will need it.